# 'Result' object has no attribute 'GetMessage', ArcGIS Example

Tags: python, arcpy, volume

i'm using the following [ArcGIS example](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q900000027000000) to calculate the surface and volume of a raster. I added the script to my toolbox:

```
'''****************************************************************************
Name: Surface Volume Example
Description: This script demonstrates how to use the 
             Surface Volume tool.

****************************************************************************'''
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import exceptions, sys, traceback

try:
    # Obtain a license for the ArcGIS 3D Analyst extension
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")
    # Set environment settings
    env.workspace = "C:/output"
    # Set Local Variables
    inSurface = "extract1"
    #Execute SurfaceVolume
    result = arcpy.SurfaceVolume_3d(inSurface, "", "BELOW", "2", "1", "5")
    print result.GetMessage(0)

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
except:
    # Get the traceback object
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    # Concatenate error information into message string
    pymsg = 'PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback info:\n{0}\nError Info:\n{1}'\
          .format(tbinfo, str(sys.exc_info()[1]))
    msgs = 'ArcPy ERRORS:\n {0}\n'.format(arcpy.GetMessages(2))
    # Return python error messages for script tool or Python Window
    arcpy.AddError(pymsg)
    arcpy.AddError(msgs)
```

The script does not work at all. The error i can't seem to avoid is

`'Result' object has no attribute 'GetMessage'`.

`SurfaceVolume_3d` works when the output is a file and the result is not printed.

I just don't understand why it does not work in the Python-Script. I couldn't find any helpful information on this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a [results object](http://resources.arcgis.com/de/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000046000000) the punctuation is slightly different than the [GetMessage](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//018v0000004t000000) method.

`print result.getMessage(0)`

Comment: Ok thank you. It worked with the lower case initial letter!

Comment: You're welcome. It's a bit funny that the esri example has the error.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I gave them feedback on this issue yesterday.